# Using CoreLocation with Apple Watchkit

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

The apple iOS/Watch simulator works great with the default Core Location implementation.

However, does this really work with the device later on? Or do I need to build my implementation around a openParentApplication-pattern?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Since your watch extension runs on the phone, it has access to the same features as a normal iOS app and can use CoreLocation.  However, it uses the CoreLocation permissions that were granted to your main app, so make sure your main app uses CoreLocation too so that the user will be asked to give your app permission to access those services.

Answer (score 0):

WatchKit extensions have access to the same technologies found in iOS apps but because they are extensions, the use of some technologies may be restricted and the use of others is not recommended.

Apple recommends to avoid using technologies that request user permission, like Core Location.

> Using the technology from your WatchKit extension could involve
>   displaying an unexpected prompt on the user’s iPhone the first time
>   you make the request. Worse, it could happen at a time when the iPhone
>   is in the user’s pocket and not visible.
>
> The best solution for performing any long-running tasks is to let your
>   iOS app perform the task instead. For example, instead of starting
>   location services in your WatchKit extension, start it in your iOS
>   app. Your iOS app can gather the needed data and put it in a shared
>   app group so that your extension can access it later.